# How to Test if a Date Falls within a Certain Range and Copy the Entire Row if So Using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a file tjhat is serving as a log of product expirations. We track it by two dates, the date as provided by the manufacturer as well as the "Effective Expiration Date". The latter is the date in which the product would expire before someone could use it as directed.

Each year is a separate Worksheet (2022, 2023, 2024, etc.) with a table named after it (_2022, _2023, etc.).

We would like to create a Macro that will go through the the current year's table as well as the one for the next two years searching for a date that falls within the range of today's date through a week later. If it finds a match, the row should be copied over to a new sheet called "Weekly Exp" that is created by the Macro.

So if I ran it today, 12/17/2022, it will search for anything with an Effective Expiration Date between 12/17/2022 and 12/24/2022.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub weeklyExpirationSheet()
    Dim dtToday As Date
    Dim dtWeekOut As Date
    Dim dtEffExp As Date
    Dim dtTest As Date
    Dim theYear As String
    Dim countDays As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim srcSheet As Worksheet
    Dim destSheet As Worksheet
    Dim srcTable As ListObject
    Dim srcRow As Range
    
    dtToday = Date
    dtWeekOut = DateAdd("ww", 1, dtToday)
    countDays = DateDiff("d", dtToday, dtWeekOut)
    
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name = "Weekly Exp" Then
            MsgBox "Weekly Audit Sheet Already Exists!"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next ws
    
    Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("Incoming")).Name = "Weekly Exp"
    Set destSheet = Worksheets("Weekly Exp")
    
    With destSheet
    
        Range("A1").Value = "UPC"
        Range("B1").Value = "Brand"
        Range("C1").Value = "Product"
        Range("D1").Value = "Sz"
        Range("E1").Value = "Expr"
        Range("F1").Value = "Eff Exp"
        Range("G1").Value = "Qty"
        Range("H1").Value = "Location"

        dtCurrentYear = CDbl(Year(Date))
        dtEndYear = CDbl(dtCurrentYear + 2)
        
        For y = dtCurrentYear To dtEndYear
            Set srcSheet = Worksheets(CStr(y))
            Set srcTable = srcSheet.ListObjects("_" & CStr(y))
            
            With srcSheet
                LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                For p = 2 To LastRow
                    dtTest = .Cells(p, "F").Value
                    If dtTest >= dtToday And dtTest <= dtWeekOut Then
                        destLastRow = destSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                        Rows(p).Copy Destination:=destSheet.Rows(destLastRow)
                    End If
                Next p
            End With
        Next y
    
    End With
    
    
End Sub
```

The code for getting the dates and such is working as is the detection/creation of the Worksheet. However when I run the Macro, it runs for a long period of time (like 3-5min) and then gives a Type Mismatch error. Nothing gets copied.

I did replace the copying code with `MsgBox` that would just display matches, it was going beyond the range. It reported an item that had a date of 12/31/2022 for example.

Edit:
This is what the data looks like

[image: Screenshot of data]

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is missing the `And` operator so it always evaluates to `True`,
Write it like this:

```
If dtTest >= dtToday And dtTest <= dtWeekOut Then
```

Comment: I added that, but it's still throwing errors. It gets a 1004 Error "Application-defined or object-defined error". When I click Debug, this line gets highlighted:

`Rows(i).Copy Destination:=destSheet.Rows(destLastRow)`

Comment: Your code refers to `Rows(i)`, but the `i` is not defined, you don't have any `i` in the code.

Comment: Getting a "Type Mismatch" error thrown now. `dtTest = .Cells(p, "F").Value` is the line highlighted. This is a column that has dates stored in mm/dd/yyyy format.

Comment: I don't get any error.  
Maybe edit your question and add a screenshot of some of your data

Comment: I added a screen shot

Comment: It looks fine, but maybe it would help `CDate(.Cells(P, "F").Value)`

Comment: Added the `CDate()` wrapper, still throws the error

Comment: Is there the error in all lines or only in some lines?

Comment: That's the only line that gets highlighted when I hit Debug.

Comment: The question is, does the error always happen or only in some of the rows of the sheet? (not in lines of code)

Comment: I am assuming it's happening right off the bat. Nothing gets copied to the "Weekly Exp" sheet.

Comment: It looks like the Type Mismatch Error was coming from something on the 2024 sheet. I took it out of the loop and I stopped getting the error. However nothing is being copied still.

Comment: You are missing a dot before this line: `Rows(p).Copy`, it should be like this: `.Rows(p).Copy Destination:=destSheet.Rows(destLastRow)`